# China $1996$ Number theory Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math

> Find the smallest positive integer $K$ such that every $K$ -element subset of $\{1,2, \ldots, 50\}$ contains two distinct elements $a, b$ such that $a+b$ divides $a b$

Let $c=g c d(a, b),$ so $a=c a_{1}$ and $b=c b_{1}$.

Therefore, $c a_{1} b_{1}$ is divisible by $a_{1}+b_{1}$

Furthermore, since $g c d\left(a_{1}, b_{1}\right)=1,$ we see that $a_{1}+b_{1}$ is relatively prime to $a_{1}$ and $b_{1},$ s $\left(a_{1}+b_{1}\right) | c$

since $a+b \leq 99 \Rightarrow a_{1}+b_{1} \leq 9 .$

**How $a+b \leq 99 \Rightarrow a_{1}+b_{1} \leq 9 .$** ???

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_1+b_1|c$  then $(a_1+b_1)^2|c(a_1+b_1)=a+b$.

Comment: I don't see how you get to "In particular [...]" this way.  More direct would just be to note $$(a_1+b_1)^2 \mid c(a_1+b_1)=a+b$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring ahh,thanks